# GridView loads items only when clicked

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-gridview

So I'm trying to create a GridView that loads images from my server that's running Parse API.

The problem that I'm having is when I load the images from the server into the GridView, I have to click on the Fragment to load them onscreen.

I have no idea why this is happening.

This is my AsyncTask:

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        thumbItemsList = new ArrayList<PostItems>();
        final String userObjectID = ProfileActivity.objectID;
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.getInBackground(userObjectID, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    try {
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> postQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                                "Post");
                        postQuery.whereEqualTo("user", parseUser);
                        postQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                        objectList = postQuery.find();
                        for (final ParseObject parseObject : objectList) {
                            thumbItems = new PostItems();
                            String first_name = parseObject.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = parseObject.getString("last_name");
                            thumbItems.setName(first_name + " " + last_name);
                            ParseFile image = (ParseFile) parseObject.get("image");
                            image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        Bitmap userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0
                                                , bytes.length);
                                        thumbItems.setImage(userImage);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("ParseException", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            thumbItemsList.add(thumbItems);
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("ParseException", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), thumbItemsList);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

And this is my GridView adapter:

```
package co.eshg.limo4.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import co.eshg.limo4.PostActivity;
import co.eshg.limo4.R;
import co.eshg.limo4.data.PostItems;
import co.eshg.limo4.data.GridViewItem;
import co.eshg.limo4.data.ThumbnailItems;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<PostItems> thumbnailsItemsList = null;
private ArrayList<PostItems> arrayList;

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<PostItems> thumbnailItemsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.thumbnailsItemsList = thumbnailItemsList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(thumbnailItemsList);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imgThumb:

            break;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {
    GridViewItem gridViewItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return thumbnailsItemsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return thumbnailsItemsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_viewpager_tab1_children, null);
        holder.gridViewItem = (GridViewItem) view.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    final Bitmap image = thumbnailsItemsList.get(position).getImage();
    holder.gridViewItem.setImageBitmap(image);

    holder.gridViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostActivity.class);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

            intent.putExtra("PostImage", byteArray);
            intent.putExtra("FullName", thumbnailsItemsList.get(position).getName());
            context.startActivity(intent, null);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

What I've tried so far is loading a local image from my drawable folder instead of the image from the server, and that works perfectly. I've done that by replacing this line from the adapter: `final Bitmap image = thumbnailsItemsList.get(position).getImage();` with `final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.dairy_back);`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> image.getDataInBackground

this line of code will get data from server. It will take a while. But you are putting it on Thread. So it will execute this **thumbItemsList.add(thumbItems)** before you get the bitmap from the server. It's cause the gridview won't load the image because the array list still don't have the bitmap value but you are already add it on the adapter.

You should add thumbItems.setUrl(stringUrlImages) and move **image.getDataInBackground** into getView method